# How do I turn off the light that comes out of my moto droid's usb port?

Tags: charging, backlight

When I plug my moto droid into a charger a bright white light comes from the micro usb port. It is super bright when its on my nightstand and the lights are out.  It drives me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Simple hack: cover it with a small strip of black sticker. Or, cover the nightstand with a handkerchief.

Complex hack: Find if the USB port driver allows you to turn the light off; I think that's quite unlikely, as it may be hardwired to the hardware itself.

Comment: Its hard to cover the light because it emits around the radius of the micro-usb plug.  I  could cover the whole phone with a handkerchief but I was hoping for a more elegant solution, that hopefully just as easy.

Comment: @Matt: an alternative to black sticker is a black permanent marker; I personally wouldn't do it that way though. A probably more elegant solution would be to find a charging/multimedia dock that would cover the USB port.